# ValidateAntiForgeryToken not working

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, controller, tokens

Hola uso Visual Studio 2019 con .net core 3.1, en la acción Create de mi controlador noto que no puedo llegar a la parte Post, pero si le quito el ValidateAntiForgeryToken, sí... algo pasa

Controlador

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
ViewData["IdCustomerCountry"] = new SelectList(_context.CustomerCountries, "CustomerCountryName", "CustomerCountryName");
return View();
}
    
// POST: CustomerRegions/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdCustomerRegion,CustomerRegionName,IdCustomerCountry")] CustomerCountryRegionVM customerCountryRegionVM)
//public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CustomerCountryRegionVM customerCountryRegionVM)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //var region = _mapper.Map<CustomerRegionsDto, CustomerCountryRegionVM>(customerRegionsDto);
      _context.Add(customerCountryRegionVM);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
   }
                
   ViewData["IdCustomerCountry"] = new SelectList(_context.CustomerCountries, "CustomerCountryName",       "CustomerCountryName");
    
  return View(customerCountryRegionVM);
}
```

Vista

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">         
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CustomerRegionName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="CustomerRegionName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CustomerRegionName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="IdCustomerCountry" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="IdCustomerCountry" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.IdCustomerCountry"></select>
            <!--Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'-->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">            
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné agregándole esto a la vista:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```